# Is it currently possible to install Drush locally on a Windows 10 PC?

Tags: drush

Is it possible to install & use Drush locally on a Windows 10 Notebook to manage Drupal sites (on shared hosting) online?
I have so far searched in vain, may be in wrong places. The places I see downloads or documentation, none seems to include Windows or in case of some tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8cX5w5wG6Q), the links related to drush on drush.org, do not seem to exist any more, such as that for "composer for Windows".

I would appreciate some specific guidance as a newbie on this.

Thank you & kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can install Drush on Windows using composer - http://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/install/

You can get composer from - https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

In theory you can manage a remote site with Drush, but you have to have ssh access to the remote server. If you have ssh access, you are better off just logging in and running it on the server. If you have multiple sites across multiple servers, then setting up site aliases in Drush makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install and use Drush on Windows 10 (and 7). The problem is to install the requirements:

- PHP
- Several Unix tools

You don't need Composer to [install Drush 8](http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/), but Drush 9 (which is the next stable release) will also require Composer.

Typically you get PHP by installing a WAMP and you get the Unix tools by installing Bash with friends - for example MSYS. There is also Cygwin. And there is an interesting "Windows Subsystem for Linux" on Windows 10 ...

Anyway, this quickly gets complicated. That is why many people just use for example [Acquia Dev Desktop](https://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop) which among many things gives you a working Drush. I assume the cleanest solution is to install the subsystem for Linux, but I haven't tried it myself.

PS! You can of course also go the virtual machine route - using virtualization to install a Linux server on your computer. [Drupal VM](https://www.drupalvm.com/) is a very interesting project.